# Using apigee , can we make multiple API talk to each other and then proxy it as single API?

Tags: apigee

I am very new to Apigee and may be what I am asking could be irrelevant to what apigee provides. But taking an excuse of being new , I will ask this question :

I have two rest apis say weather and traffic. And I also have a mobile app or say some app that wants to talk to apigee apis. Now can apigee be configured such that both rest apis interact with other and give a new service altogether .. something like "Should I get out on the road now ? "

I am trying to avoid code in app and instead want both the api talkt to each other figure out and then tell app what to do.

I hope I am making sense as I am using general words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is whether two apis can be mashed/orchestrated and exposed as single api which app can then consume to decide. This is quite achievable with apigee least configurations, you will definitely need some logic what weather is good and how much traffic is bad..

The link describes a very similar use case http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/cookbook/using-policy-composition 
hope this helps.